# UIView frame Sequence Animation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimageview

This is my code for block-animation:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:.5f delay:15.0f options:UIViewAnimationTransitionNone animations:^{
        animationContainer.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Hear 1_00.png"];
    }completion:^(BOOL finished){
        if(! finished) return;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:.5f delay:15.0f options:UIViewAnimationTransitionNone animations:^{
            animationContainer.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Hear 1_01.png"];
        }completion:^(BOOL finished){
            if(! finished) return;
      }];

    }];
```

I want to animate a FRAME sequence with 320x480 (full screen of iPhone).  I have 120 pictures, and if I try try to animate them with an `NSArray`, the iPhone seems to become slow.  Do you have a suggestion or sample code that you can share with me or suggest? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should use built-in animation functionality of `UIImageView`:

```
animationContainer.animationImages = imagesArray;
animationContainer.animationDuration = 0.5f;
[animationContainer startAnimating];
```

Look at `UIImageView` documentation for more information.

And if you want smooth animation of image appearance it's better to use `NSTimer` instead of delay parameter. Just fire timer every 15 seconds and present next image with any animation you want. Make sure your images are smallest to be displayed on the screen. Because if they are huge it may take ages to resize and draw it. Prepare resized images array before starting animation sequence if you can't change original images.